# Problema para logearme con PHP

Tags: php

Mi problema es el siguiente; En el if donde hago la comparación de $fila distinto de null, no sé por qué razón el valor sí que es null y por lo tanto me salta el error que tengo en el else.

Aquí mi código:

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){

        $usuario_entrar=$_POST["usuario_entrar"];
        $contrasenha_entrar=$_POST["contrasenha_entrar"];

        if(empty($usuario_entrar) || empty($contrasenha_entrar)){

            echo("ERRO. Debes introducir un nome de usuario e un contrasinal correctos.  <br />");

        }else{

            require_once("conexion_bd.php");

            try{

                $resultado_entrar=$mysqli->stmt_init();
                $resultado_entrar->prepare("SELECT usuario, contrasenha FROM datos_personales WHERE usuario=? AND contrasenha=?");
                $resultado_entrar->bind_param("ss",$usuario_entrar,$contrasenha_entrar);
                $resultado_entrar->execute();
                $resultado_entrar->bind_result($usuario_entrar,$contrasenha_entrar);

                $fila=$resultado_entrar->fetch_rows();

                if($fila!=null){

                   session_start();
                   $_SESSION["usuario_entrar"]=$usuario_entrar;
                   //header("Location: contenido.php");
                   echo("Correcto!");

                }else{

                   echo("ERRO. Usuario ou contrasinal non válidos. <br />");

                }

            }catch(Exception $mysqli_ex2){

                die("Produciuse o seguinte erro: " . "<br />" . $mysqli_ex2->getMessage() . "<br />" . $mysqli_ex2->getCode() .  "<br />");

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Que te devuelve si haces `var_dump($fila);`

Comment: Me devuelve "int 0". Cambié "fetch_row" por "num_rows" porque me estaba saltando un error de método indefinido ahí.

Comment: bien.. entonces si te devuelve 0 es porque no tienes resultado.. comprueba el porque...(algún otro error? la query funciona en la consola?)...a parte cambia `if ($fila != null)` a `if ($fila === 1)` así te aseguras que haya solo 1 resultado si todo va bien...

Comment: Es un fallo tipográfico: la función no es `fetch_rows` sino [`fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) (sin la s), aunque podría haber más errores por ahí. Y `num_rows` te falla porque es una propiedad, pero lo estás llamando como si fuera un método (con paréntesis, por eso dice que es un método indefinido)

Comment: La consulta funciona en la consola y si imprimo las variables de usuario y contraseña, sí que tienen el valor correcto. El error que me salta ahora es en la lína donde declaré la variable $fila y es: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_row() in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, ya está solucionado. El problema estaba en que antes de `$fila = $resultado->fetch_row();` debería haber puesto `$resultado = $resultado_entrar->get_result();` para conseguir rescatar la query.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!